# how can I expand this for $k$

Tags: mathematica

$$\sinh\sqrt{k^2-\Omega^2}$$ for $k$ in Mathematica.

How do I expand this in Mathematica for $k$.

In general,
What would be the expansion of $\sin x$ in powers of $n$? in Mathematica

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $$\text{Series}\left[\sinh \left(k^2-\Omega ^2\right),\{k,0,6\}\right]$$$$-\sinh \left(\Omega ^2\right)+k^2 \cosh \left(\Omega ^2\right)-\frac{1}{2} k^4 \sinh \left(\Omega ^2\right)+\frac{1}{6} k^6 \cosh \left(\Omega ^2\right)+O\left(k^7\right)$$

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html